# How to add multiple conditions in On clause using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Being database table A, B and AB (AB is a many to many association between A and B tables) and haveing in `Entity Frameworc Core` database context only tables A and B declared as `DbSet`, how can I perform the following sql statment using `LINQ` to `SQL`

```
SELECT A.Id, A.Name
FROM A
LEFT JOIN AB ON AB.AId = A.Id AND AB.BId = @myVariable
WHERE AB.AId IS NULL
```

The following `LINQ`

```
var result = (from a in _context.A
              from t in a.ABs
                  .DefaultIfEmpty()
                  .Where(x => x.BId == @variable)
              where t == null
              select a)
return result.ToListAsync();
```

Generates the following `SQL`

```
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[Name]
FROM [A] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT [ab].[AId], [ab].[BId]
     FROM [AB] AS [ab]
     WHERE [ab].[BId] = @__variable_0
) AS [t] ON [i].[Id] = [t].[AId]
WHERE [t].[BId] IS NULL
```

How can I update my `LINQ` in order to avoid subquery statement, without adding AB table as `DbSet` property in `Entity Framework` context?

Comment: It is still not fixed "feature" https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17622